# Can I select CSS siblings out of order?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to write css to style my columns automatically based on the elements on the page. There are several combinations of columns:

`aside`-`article`-`aside`

`aside`-`article`

`article`-`aside`

`article`

Each `aside` will have a class of either left or right, depending on which side of the screen it is on. The `aside`s will always be a constant width no matter what the layout, but the `article`'s width will change depending on the layout.

I want to use CSS (preferably without any javascript) to set the width of the `article`. I've been playing around with CSS siblings, but I can't quite get this to work. This is how I would theoretically like the code to work:

```
article{
   /* just article */
   width: some width;
   }
.left~article{
   /* aside-article */
   width: some width;
   }
.right~article{
   /* article-aside */
   width: some width; /* (this can be the same as the previous;
                         I don't know if it's easier to define
                         them together or separately) */
   }
.left~.right~article{
   /* aside-article-aside */
   width: some-width;
   }
```

The first two layouts work, bu the second two do not. The problem is that I always want to style the `article`, even if it is not the last in that section of the DOM. Using the selectors `article~.right` and `.left~.article~.right` for the last two layouts respectively finds the correct combination of layouts (i.e. either an `article` then an `aside` or an `article` between two `aside`s) but then it targets the right-most `aside` and I can't change the style of the `article`.

Is there a way to take all siblings into account whether before the target element in the DOM using the sibling selectors in CSS? Or can anyone think of any "creative" ways I could get around this without having to use javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: "Is there a way to take all siblings into account whether before the target element in the DOM using the sibling selectors in CSS?" No because the sibling selectors are one-way only.

Comment: Not an answer, but maybe interesting nonetheless, here's an article on the dangers of selecting specific elements and descendants too much instead of just using classes: http://csswizardry.com/2012/10/a-classless-class-on-using-more-classes-in-your-html/. Your css will become hard to maintain and your html even more so.

Comment: @BoltClock--for this particular instance (and an assumption on my part for structure), there is a way. See my answer.

Comment: @ScottS: Yes, that looks good - just upvoted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### CSS3 Solution

Assuming the containing element for these only has immediate children of either `aside` or `article`, then there is a CSS3 solution (so IE9+). [For my example here](http://jsfiddle.net/4pZe9/5/), I am assuming an overall `width` of `400px` and standard widths for `aside` elements (though that could be different).

```
aside {
    width: 100px;
}

aside.left + article,
article:first-child {
    width: 300px;
}

article:only-child {
    width: 400px; /* overrides article:first-child if it is only-child */
}

aside.left:nth-last-of-type(2) + article {
    width: 200px; /* only engages if there are two asides */
}
```